# Linear two color smooth & sharp gradient using SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I tried all the CSS tricks to make the linear gradient as follows for my `body` tag.

[image]

but the CSS gradient is not sharp, so I tried the trick as follows,

```
<body><div class="bg"></div></body>
```

```css
.bg{ 
  background-color:red; 
  width:3000px; 
  height:3000px;
  overflow:hidden
} 
.bg:before{ 
  left: 7%; 
  top:-20%; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; 
  transform:rotate(25deg) 
}
```

So, I achieved the green rectangle. I can now see the sharp gradient.

But I have to write `media` queries to adjust the rotation for each size.

And I thought that if we can draw a triangle using SVG on this div starting from `(0, 0)` to `(body width, body height)` I could really make a responsive linear gradient.

But I am very new to SVG, how can I achieve the responsive inverse right angle triangle using SVG?

> In short, I want a responsive two colored `smooth &` **`sharp`** gradient background.

Update:

[image]

Complete css code is here.

```
div.bg {
  margin-top: -50px;
  position: fixed;
  height: 1500px;
  width: 3500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: @bg-gradient-color-1;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -999999;
}

.bg:before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  background-color: @bg-gradient-color-2;
  z-index: -999999;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1320px) {
  .bg:before {
    left: 0%;
    top: -106%;
    transform: rotate(27deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: what, you mean like this: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ff070b+0,00db15+100 - there is no need to use svg just for the requested gradient

Comment: I tried it birdspider, it is not responsive and not smooth to use for complete body tag

Comment: Your posted code doesn't really do anything but create a large red square. And the image you've posted doesn't show a "gradient" at all. Perhaps you've forgotten something.

Comment: @LonelyPlanet, I'm not sure what you mean but my link works as demo'd here: https://jsfiddle.net/tgbmzfhL/ , it's smooth and fills whole of body (if you have a recent enough browser, which one do you use btw?)

Comment: I use chrome 48.x version. Pls see the screenshot I attached in question, which shows the two blur colors

Comment: @LonelyPlanet, yeah well you use a gradient with 4 colors, in gradient-editor remove the medium ones by dragging them.

Comment: pls see this https://jsfiddle.net/tgbmzfhL/1/, if you take a closer look at the gradient, the line which separates two color is not sharp

Comment: And I am sorry, instead of SHARP, I said smooth.

Comment: @LonelyPlanet you don't need to use `50% 51%` for your gradient. `50% 50%` is allowed. It becomes sharp when you do that: https://jsfiddle.net/tgbmzfhL/2/

Comment: @PaulLeBeau: Spot on, but CSS gradients does tend to get jagged along the diagonals at higher dimensions. I can see that in the CSS gradient in my answer as well as the fiddle.

Comment: I know Firefox has a bug where those sharp transitions in CSS gradients are jaggy and not antialiased properly. I believe that's just been fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this with two `path` elements in SVG and then give them the fill as required.

```css
svg path#green {
  fill: green;
}
svg path#red {
  fill: red;
}
div.bg {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
div.bg svg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='bg'>
  <svg viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
    <path d='M0,0 L100,100 100,0z' id='green' />
    <path d='M0,0 L0,100 100,100z' id='red' />
  </svg>
</div>
```

---

**Original Answer:** (missed reading the *not smooth* part due to oversight)

You can do this with just a gradient which uses the `to [side] [side]` syntax. But as you've said, it does produce jagged edges along the diagonal lines when the dimensions are high.

```css
.bg {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, red 50%, green 50%);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: Though the gradients jagged at some dimensions, for the light colors I see it very minute. @Harry, it's very simplest & great answer. Thank you

Comment: This unfortunately is not always smooth/antialiased at different widths or on different browsers. Safari & Chrome in particular seem to have jagged borders depending on the angle and width of the browser. Sometimes smooth, sometimes not.

Answer (score 4):

The simple way to produce the SVG you want is probably with Harry's approach - with two triangles - or a triangle on top of a rectangle.

However, it can be done with a gradient as well.  One advantage of this approach is that you don't get any anti-aliasing issues where the edges of the two colours coincide.

```css
svg stop.color1 {
  stop-color: green;
}
svg stop.color2 {
  stop-color: red;
}
div.bg {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 60vw;
}
div.bg svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='bg'>
  <svg viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="grad" x2="1" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0.5" class="color1"/>
        <stop offset="0.5" class="color2"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#grad)"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```